# Repeating letters being truncated

Tags: languages, localization, bugs

About a month ago, I noticed a strange issue anywhere a repeating letter a appears on my Android phone: repeating letters are either truncated or replaced with a single letter that has a macron (bar/ line) above it. I have noticed this issue in nearly every application on the phone. Note that my phone should be configured for only US English and not any other languages. How can I get rid of this?

The phone is a Verizon Samsung Galaxy SIII running stock Android 4.3

Here are some examples:
[image: NOAA to NOĀ, Firefox]
NOAA to NOĀ, Firefox
[image: Klaas to Klās, Google Play Music]
Klaas to Klās, Google Play Music
[image: Paas and Iaas to Pās and Iās, Google+]
Paas and Iaas to Pās and Iās, Google+

Comment: When you noticed the issue, had you recently done anything such as installing new apps, travelling abroad with your phone, or changing any system settings?

Comment: To be honest, I don't have the start date for this issue nailed down at all. Because it's very subtle, I either failed to notice it or just wrote it off as a fluke at first. I know it began in either February or March of 2014, but a sizeable number of app updates/installs and settings changes could have occurred in that time span. However, I do know that I have never traveled abroad with my phone, and I have not applied any firmware updates during the relevant time period.

Comment: Did you install an alternate keyboard with its own dictionary?

Comment: I do have the Google keyboard installed, but i installed that in mid-2013

Comment: Update: while this almost always appears with the letter a, I have seen it happen at least once with the letter i.